# MS SSMS - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssms-2014

I am facing an issue in MS- Sql Server Management studio 2014. Upon writing a query and executing it in SSMS, i get the following error.
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation)**

I have uninstalled and installed SSMS and Visual Studio several times to make it work but have not been successful. Have also gone through google and a lot of forums but no luck yet.
I had VS 2015 installed which i have uninstalled and yet getting the error in SSMS.

Here is the additional info:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   12.0.2000.8
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools     12.0.2000.8
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  6.1.7601.17514
- Microsoft MSXML              3.0 4.0 6.0
- Microsoft Internet Explorer          9.11.9600.18893
- Microsoft .NET Framework         4.0.30319.42000
- Operating System             6.1.7601

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to get this fixed. This issue was due to a security patch with a defect. I uninstalled the security patch**(KB 4055002)** from .Net framework and it started working fine.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, and exactly the same versions listed above from the SMSS Help | About info.
Our support team didn't want to do the 'uninstall update', worried it might cause ripples, so one of them used the 'FixitTool' MS built and recommended, at this page: 
https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/53
as 'Solution 1'.
That did the trick for my PC.

Comment: kzoom - would like to upvote your's as solution as I prefer installing that vs uninstalling patch.

Comment: Even I am facing this issue with both SSMS 2012 and SSMS 2014 on my machine, and I do not have KB4055002 installed on my machine. What can be other contributing factors ? any suggestions ?